# Remove group labels from car::scatter3d() in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d, scatter3d

I have something like this and I want to remove the group labels from the ellipsoids

```
car::scatter3d(x, y, z, groups = group, surface=FALSE, grid = FALSE, ellipsoid = TRUE)
```

Is there a way to remove the group labels because there are overlapping and cannot be distinguished?

An illustrative example is:

```
car::scatter3d(x = iris$Sepal.Length, y = iris$Sepal.Width, z = iris$Petal.Length, groups = iris$Species, surface=FALSE, grid=FALSE, ellipsoid = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Elli. Welcome to SO!
Could you add a reproducible example to your question so that it can be answered more clearly and easily? Check this question for some tips on reproducible examples in R: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

This problem has driven me crazy for years and I haven't found a solution. The best workaround I could come up with was to change the group labels to "." and "*" so that they are barely noticeable in the plot. If I could even change the size, color, or position of the group labels that might be a better solution, but I cannot figure out how to do that either! Ideally, I would really like to be able to remove the group labels that are automatically added when ellipsoid=T as well!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Using the illustrative example in the question above, please modify your answer to actually provide the code needed to complete your suggestion (i.e. changing the group labels).